# Google sheets, calculate sum if the cell above the formula is not empty

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, sum

The title explains everything.

What I have so far:

```
=SUMIF(COUNTA(C4!=N(C4*Sheet2!H1-Sheet2!E4-A3)))
```

Original formula:

```
=sum(C4*Sheet2!H1-Sheet2!E4-A3)
```

So the formula is in cell **C5**, I want the the code to execute only if the cell above it has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C4), ,sum(C4*Sheet2!H1-Sheet2!E4-A3))
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. All i had to do was change C4 to C5 in your formula.